Measurability of a complex function
Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space, $u,v:X\to \mathbb{R}$ two measurable functions and then consider the complex function $f=u+iv:X\to \mathbb{C}$. Then, $f$ is measurable.
My teacher concludes immediately saying that on $\mathbb{C}$ there is the direct image topology through the function $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$.
Well, I don't undestand precisely this fact and I was wondering what sigma algebra we put on $\mathbb{C}$ using that topology. Any help is pleasantly welcome!

Consider $\varphi: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb C$, where $\varphi(x,y) =x + iy$.
We know that the space $\Bbb R^2$ has a topology (the product topology of $\Bbb R$).
We can define a topology on $\Bbb C$ as the direct image topology through $\varphi$. It means $U \subseteq \Bbb C$ is open if and only if $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2 $.
In other words: $U \subseteq \Bbb C$ is open if and only $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x +iy \in U \}$ is open in $\Bbb R^2 $.
We put on $\Bbb C$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that topology. It is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb C$, and we can write $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ to indicate it. We can also write $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$ to indicate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^2$.
It can be proved that:  $E \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ if and only $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x +iy \in E \} \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$.
Remark: We have that $E \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ if and only $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x +iy \in E \} \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$. It means $E \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ if and only $\varphi^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$. It is immediate that $\varphi$ is $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$ - $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ measurable.
Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space, $u,v:X\to \mathbb{R}$ two measurable functions and then $g = (u,v) : X\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathcal{M}$ - $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$ measurable. It follows immedately that $f= \varphi \circ g = u+iv:X\to \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathcal{M}$ - $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb C)$ measurable.

Ok thanks, everything is much clearer now. Therefore, the last characterization is the one that gives me the measurability of $f$ since this implies to me that the counterimages of an open set of that topology are in $\mathcal{M}$ given that the functions $u,v$ are both measurable?

@SigmaAlgebra Exactly.

In essence, $(u+iv)^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{M}$ for all $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$ because $u,v$ are measurable and a sum of measurable functions is measurable?

That means, $(u+iv)^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{M} \iff \varphi^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which is true because $\varphi$ is a sum of measurable functions?

How can I write the idea correctly?

@SigmaAlgebra , I added a remark to the answer with the details.

Thank you very much!!!
